# Android Facebook Video Upload with Graph API - How to use multipart/form-data

Tags: android, facebook, facebook-graph-api, video

I am implementing [Video Upload with Graph API](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/graph-api/video-uploads#) and I don't understand the chunks part. It says

> The request parameters are:
>
> - upload_phase (enum) - Set to transfer upload_session_id (int32) - The
> - session id returned in the start phase start_offset (int32) - Start
> - byte position of this chunk video_file_chunk (multipart/form-data) -
> - The video chunk, encoded as form data

And they provide the next example

```
curl \
  -X POST \
  "https://graph-video.facebook.com/v2.3/1533641336884006/videos"  \
  -F "access_token=XXXXXXX" \
  -F "upload_phase=transfer" \
  -F “start_offset=0" \
  -F "upload_session_id=1564747013773438" \
  -F "video_file_chunk=@chunk1.mp4"
```

I don't understand the `video_file_chunk` part. How do I encode it to `multipart/form-data`? All what I got is a file, and I can read bytes from it.

Comment: Instead of building the whole upload process manually, have you checked out what the SDK already offers for this purpose, like the `ShareVideo*` classes?

Comment: @CBroe sure, there is nothing else. This is the only way. ShareVideo is limited to 12MB

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found the solution using [Android Async](https://github.com/koush/AndroidAsync) Library

```
Ion.with(context)
                .load(url)
                .uploadProgress(progressCallback)
                .setMultipartParameter("access_token", AccessToken.getCurrentAccessToken().getToken())
                .setMultipartParameter("upload_phase", "transfer")
                .setMultipartParameter("upload_session_id", Long.toString(uploadSessionId))
                .setMultipartParameter("start_offset", Long.toString(startOffset))
                .setMultipartFile("video_file_chunk", chunkFile)
                .asByteArray()
                .setCallback(completeCallback);
```